# Issue with RSS and WordPress

Tags: wordpress, hootsuite

I get the following issue using my WordPress RSS in Hootsuite.

[image]

Comment: Its working from here. [link](http://i.imgur.com/SHnWAlP.png)

Comment: It doesn't work on my account. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Contact for support. They are very responsive.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the format for the URL should have the ending forward slash on it.

So change the feed value to:

```
http://icecom.fr/feed/
```